# Как решается задача про прибавление к часам, минутам, секундам?

Tags: c

**Задача:**

> Текущее показание электронных часов: m часов (0<=m<=23), n мин
>   (0<=n<=59), k сек (0<=k<=59). Какое время будут показывать часы через
>   p ч d мин r c?

(Задача по теме "Линейные алгоритмы", но я, пробуя её решить, превысил ограничение). 
Моя проба:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

    int h, m, s;
    long int h_, m_, s_;
    h=23; m=59; s=59;
    printf("Текущее время: %d : %d : %d",h,m,s);


    printf("\nВведите поправку: часы, затем минуты и секунды");
    scanf("%ld%ld%ld",&h_,&m_,&s_);

    if ( h+h_>=0 && h+h_<=23 )
    printf ("Новое значение часов: %d", h+h_ )

    if ( h+h_<=23+24 && h+h_>=0+24 )
    printf("Новое значение часов: %d", h+h_-24);

    if ( h+h_>=24+24 && h+h_<=47+24)
    printf("Новое значение часов: %d", h+h_-24*2);
        ...
        ... 
        // некий цикл
```

Comment: Либо просто переводите все в секунды, считайте в секундах и затем переводите обратно в `h:m:s`. Либо аккуратно реализуйте суммирование с переносом, причем сначала суммируются именно секунды, затем минуты и только в последнюю очередь часы.

Comment: А для времени нет никакой библиотечки, чтобы не переводить самому??? аля `<time.h>`?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Разумеется, есть... Может, так и надо, но я предположил, что не надо (мы её "не проходили"). Я спрошу.

Comment: Тег `[циклы]`? Почему на вопросе стоит этот тег? И зачем в коде стоит комментарий про "некий цикл"? Откуда взялся цикл?

Comment: Можно убрать. Просто мне казалось, что тут есть цикл. Уберу тогда...

Comment: @AnT Ну, мне хотелось показать, что я и сам сначала потрудился, а не просто так... Закономерность есть, сами посмотрите, она обозначена, а где закономерность - там и цикл :)

Comment: Эта "закономерность" назвается "остаток от деления на 24", и вычисляется он оператором `%` без каких-либо циклов. Однако сразу можно сказать, что невозможно вычислить новое значение часов, не принимая во внимание поведение минут и секунд. Так что написанное у вас заведомо не верно.

Comment: @AnT Я и не говорил, что верно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все просто - складываете в столбик в 60-ричной системе. Я считаю, что все вводимые числа - положительны. Если есть отрицательные - пишется аналогично, но с заемом из следующего разряда...

```
printf("\nВведите поправку: часы, затем минуты и секунды");
scanf("%ld%ld%ld",&p,&d,&r);

// Начинаем с секунд

s += r;
// Перенос, остаток:

m += s/60;
s %= 60;

// Минуты

m += d;
h += m/60;
m %= 60;

h += p;
h %= 24;
```

Comment: На что поделить -1, чтобы в остатке получить 23? (Вводим -24). Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы видели мое примечание? *"Я считаю, что все вводимые числа - положительны."*? А вообще, достаточно прибавить 24 (если речь о часах).

Comment: Получается ветвление (для положительных h %= 24, для отрицательных - другое). Во-вторых, для отрицательных: -1+24=23 - всё правильно, -25+24 - уже не работает, так что недостаточно прибавить 24.

Comment: вы сначала отработайте остаток, а уж потом прибавляйте. Понятно, что так работать будет плохо.

Comment: -48 % 24 + 24 = 24, а не о; кроме того 1000 % 24 = 16 + 24, т.е. ветвление всё-таки нужно...

Comment: Про 1000 вообще не понял. 1000%24 == 16. И вообще - см. https://ideone.com/p9ndgm

Comment: Ок, [алгоритм](http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread2337450.html#post12986932) понял.

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread2337450.html#post13020572

Answer (score 1):

```
считываем [h_] [m_] [s_];
считаываем на сколько нужно перевести [h] [m] [s];
//переводим и то и то в секунды
int tempNextSec = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s;
int tempSec = h_ * 3600 + m_ * 60 + s_;
// Сложим
int curSec = tempSec + tempNextSec;
// Отнимем дни и округлим к меньшему
if ( floor(curSec / 60*60*24) > 0)  curSec = curSec - 60*60*24 * floor(curSec / 60*60*24);
// Узнаем сколько часов
int tempHour = floor(curSec / 3600);
//Можно вывести..
//Теперь отнимем от общего
curSec -=tempHour*3600;
// Минуты
int tempMinutes = floor(curSec / 60);
// Так же можно вывести...
// Секунды
curSec -= tempMinutes * 60
```

Это алгоритм...написал бы кодом, если бы знал C )))

Comment: Используйте остатки от деления, и floor-ы не понадобятся.

Comment: @MBo написал же что алгоритм, а флор это для понимания...а то вообще не понятно бы было) я так понимаю что а второй - новичек)

Comment: Работа в секундах - хорошая идея, а использование развесистой вещественной арифметики там, где достаточно curSec = curSec% (60*60*24) - плохая.